# How can I define my Remote Action Apex Controller class for JavaScript in a VisualForce Page?

Tags: javascript, apex, javascript-remoting, visualforce-charting, remote-action

Currently looking at [Providing Chart Data Using a JavaScript Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_providing_data_javascript_function.htm)

The chart is not rendering for me; not at all, though I have confirmed that the JavaScript getRemoteData() method is attempted.

Using Chrome's debugger, I managed to find

> Visualforce Chart: Error loading configuration for chart 'jid0jid2': VF_PieChartVFCtrl is not defined

Here is my VisualForce page:

```
   <apex:page >
    <script>
        function getRemoteData(callback) 
        {
            VF_PieChartVFCtrl.getRemotePieData(function(result, event) 
            {
               if(event.status && result && result.constructor === Array) 
               {
                   callback(result);
               }
           });
        }
    </script>
    <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="getRemoteData">
        <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name" />
        <apex:legend position="right" />
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

What do I need to add to get my browser to communicate with the controller?

If it makes any difference, my organization has a namespace ("Sledgehammer"),
but neither

- Sledgehammer.VF_PieChartVFCtrl.getRemotePieData(function(result, event)
- Sledgehammer__VF_PieChartVFCtrl.getRemotePieData(function(result, event)

seemed any more effective.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to assign the class that houses the function to your page. Use either the controller attribute, or the extensions attribute if you need to mix in multiple controllers. Also, if you're in an iframe, you also need to make the class global. Finally, use the $RemoteAction global variable to automatically reference your call correctly. See the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) for example code.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The example on the "Providing Chart Data Using a JavaScript Function" documentation I linked to does not seem to include this, but made it seem much simpler... currently seeing if the page you referred to can help out...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't work before, but I added the namespace (again) and this works now:

```
<apex:page controller="VF_PieChartVFCtrl">
<script>
    function getRemoteData(callback) 
    {
        Sledgehammer.VF_PieChartVFCtrl.getRemotePieData(function(result, event) 
        {
           if(event.status && result && result.constructor === Array) 
           {
               callback(result);
           }
       });
    }
</script>
<apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="getRemoteData">
    <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name" />
    <apex:legend position="right" />
</apex:chart>
```